# How do you explain the output from this function-like macro `slice` in C?

Tags: c, string, macros

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define slice(bare_string,start_index) #bare_string+start_index
#define arcane_slice(bare_string,start_index) "ARCANE" #bare_string+start_index

int main(){
    printf("slice(FIRSTA,0)==> `%s`\n",slice(FIRSTA,0));
    printf("slice(SECOND,2)==> `%s`\n",slice(SECOND,2));
    printf("slice(THIRDA,5)==> `%s`\n",slice(THIRDA,5));
    printf("slice(FOURTH,6)==> `%s`\n",slice(FOURTH,6));
    printf("slice(FIFTHA,7)==> `%s`\n",slice(FIFTHA,7));
    printf("arcane_slice(FIRSTA,0)==> `%s`\n",arcane_slice(FIRST,0));
    printf("arcane_slice(SECOND,2)==> `%s`\n",arcane_slice(SECOND,2));
    printf("arcane_slice(THIRDA,5)==> `%s`\n",arcane_slice(THIRDA,5));
    printf("arcane_slice(FOURTH,6)==> `%s`\n",arcane_slice(FOURTH,6));
    printf("arcane_slice(FIFTHA,7)==> `%s`\n",arcane_slice(FIFTHA,7));
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
slice(FIRSTA,0)==> `FIRSTA`
slice(SECOND,2)==> `COND`
slice(THIRDA,5)==> `A`
slice(FOURTH,6)==> ``
slice(FIFTHA,7)==> `slice(FIFTHA,7)==> `%s`
`
arcane_slice(FIRSTA,0)==> `ARCANEFIRST`
arcane_slice(SECOND,2)==> `CANESECOND`
arcane_slice(THIRDA,5)==> `ETHIRDA`
arcane_slice(FOURTH,6)==> `FOURTH`
arcane_slice(FIFTHA,7)==> `IFTHA`
```

I have the above C code that I need help on. I am getting weird behaviour from
 
the function-like macro `slice` that is supposed to 'slice' from a passed index
to the end of the string. It does not slice in the real sense but passes
a pointer from a certain point to `printf` which starts printing from that
address. I have managed to figure out that in `arcane_slice` the strings
are concatenated first then 'sliced'. I also have figured out that when `start_index`
is equal to 6 `printf` starts printing from the null byte and that is why
you get the 'empty' string. The strange part is when `start_index` is 7. It prints
the first argument to `printf`(interpolator string) concatendated with the passed bare string in both.
`arcane_slice` and `slice`(as shown in the 5th and 10th lines in the output)
**Why is that so?**
My wildest guess is that when the `start_index` exceeds the length of the strings,
the pointer points to the start of the data segment in the program's address space. But
then you could counter that with "why didn't it start printing from `FIRSTA`"

Comment: Your "*wildest guess*" is the right one. However exceeding the properly allocated memory for the character array invokes undefined behaviour, so anything could happend. Just do not do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not any "data segment", the stack. This is what I remember: when C calls a function it first puts data on stack, first variable arguments, then the format, all being the addresses to the memory sequentially allocated with your text. In that block of memory, the last argument (c-string) goes first, and the first goes last, thus:

Memory:

```
"FIFTHA\0slice(FIFTHA,7)==> `%s`\n\0"
```

Arguments:

```
<pointer-to-"FIFTHA"> <pointer-to-"slice...">
```

Since you overincrement the first one it skips the `'\0'` character and points at the format as well.

Try to experiment with this with more placeholders, like

```
 printf("1: %s, 2: %s\n", slice(FIFTHA,7), slice(FIFTHA,6));
```

Comment: it doesn't exactly reproduce the same output. It's really undefined(if 
undefinedness can be quantified). I'm getting null bytes and high ascii characters.

Comment: Damn, my comments are messed up. Rishta's comments were supposed to be Gangadhar's and vice versa. I found rishta's answer the most helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

```
 slice(bare_string,start_index) #bare_string+start_index
```

you are passing a `string` and `bare_string` stores the starting address of string which you have passed and then you returning changed pointer location which is `bare_string+start_index`

```
char str[6]="Hello";

char *ptr =str;

printf("%s\n",str);//prints hello

printf("%s\n",str+1);//prints ello
printf("%s\n",str+2);//prints llo
printf("%s\n",str+3);//prints lo
printf("%s\n",str+4);//prints o
printf("%s %c=%d  \n",str+5,*(str+5),*(str+5));//prints Null
printf("%s %c=%d  \n",str+6,*(str+6),*(str+6));//prints Null or may be Undefined behavior
printf("%s %c=%d  \n",str+7,*(str+7),*(str+7));//prints Null or may be Undefined behaviour
```

the same scenario is happing in your case.

Test Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
char str[6]="Hello";

char *ptr =str;

printf("%s\n",str);//prints hello

printf("%s\n",str+1);//prints ello
printf("%s\n",str+2);//prints llo
printf("%s\n",str+3);//prints lo
printf("%s\n",str+4);//prints o
printf("%s %c=%d  \n",str+5,*(str+5),*(str+5));//prints Null
printf("%s %c=%d  \n",str+6,*(str+6),*(str+6));//prints Null or may be Undefined behavior
printf("%s %c=%d  \n",str+7,*(str+7),*(str+7));//prints Null or may be Undefined behaviour

}
```

Comment: The explanation does make some little sense. I wasn't aware of the first and  
last thing. However, if the address of the last character('\n') is say 1222222  
and you add 7(more than the string length) the pointer should be at 1222229 if  
char is a byte. This surely can't be the same as the address of the first character('F')  
in printf("slice(FIFTHA,7)==> `%s`\n"). Furthermore, if you have `start_index` as 42 onwards  
it starts printing the first arguments of `printf` below e.g `start_index` of 45 leads to  
`rcane_slice(FIRSTA,0)==> `%s`.

Comment: It's like all the first arguments of `printf` are strung together  
into one long string. I have played with it a bit, and it goes on till `start_index` is about 267.
After that, it starts encroaching on memory space used by GCC e.g at 272 it prints `Mingw runtime failure:`  
I think it's safe to say that the behavior is undefined when you go out of bounds. I was hopping for  
any other answer but 'the behavior is undefined'. It still leaves me with more questions though. Like,  
How come all this time there hasn't been a segfault? Why is the output different from that of @Gangadhar?

Comment: @Segfault As you said "if the address of the last character is say 1222222 and you add 7(more than the string length) the pointer should be at 1222229 if char is a byte. ",this is absolutely correct. How did you said "This surely can't be the same as the address of the first character('F') in printf("slice(FIFTHA,7)==> %s\n")." i have tried with different values i got the appropriate  results on GCC and on turbo-C.

Comment: Sorry @Gangadhar, my comment was a little misleading. I didn't really get that error. The program read from a memory location that happened to have the string "Mingw runtime failure". What's being output changes almost everytime you run ite.g I'm getting "  VirtualQuery failed for %d bytes at address %p" at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your question yourself.  `"FIFTHA"+7` gives you a pointer outside the string object, which is undefined behavior in C.

There's no easy way to get a more Python-like behavior for such "slices" in C.  You could make it work for indexes up to a certain upper limit by adding a suffix to your string, full of zero bytes:

```
#define slice(bare_string,start_index) ((#bare_string "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0")+(start_index))
```

Also, when using macros, it's good practice (and avoids bugs too) to use parentheses excessively.

```
#define slice(bare_string,start_index) ((#bare_string)+(start_index))
#define arcane_slice(bare_string,start_index) (("ARCANE" #bare_string)+(start_index))
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @nickie, you read my mind. I was trying to come up with a way to do python-like slices(it's fun to abuse the preprocessor). The additional braces don't seem to improve it though.